# How do I resume screen activity for more than one activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

So I have these two screens, Messages screen and Game screen. What I want to do is when the user switches back from either screen, it resumes from the previous activity.

This is a bit of code in my Game screen that allows the user to go to the Messages screen:

```
public void onMessagesButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Messages.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

And this is a bit of code that allows the user to go from the Messages screen back to the Game screen.

```
public void onGameButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Game.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

So far I am able to go from the Game screen to the Messages screen, then go from the Messages screen and resume activity in the Game screen.

The problem I now have is I can't resume activity from the Messages screen, only the Game screen. If I were to update the `onMessagesButtonClick()` to:

```
public void onMessagesButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Messages.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

I will no longer be able to resume activity from the Game screen. It will be as if I am entering the screen for the first time, starting the screen fresh.

What can I do to be able to resume previous activity from both screens when going back and forth between screens?

Comment: Use onSaveInstanceState to save the state of the activity, and get the state back in the bundle savedInstanceState in onCreate(). It's not that hard.

Comment: @Bert Hanz: I think you should understand about [using Intent Flag](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#IntentFlagsForTasks) for starting an activity

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` to take you to the correct screen.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
public void onGameButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

on your game class

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             //If you are going to fetch data from former activity
            }
    }
}
```